# Test react component can't get clientWidth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to develop unit test for my react component with jest and enzyme. So basically my component have resize listener, when resize occured my component will update component state. But i just couldn't get the clientWidth for my react component. Below is some code of my component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
// import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Table from "./Table";
import Grid from "./Grid";
import ActionBlock from "../ActionBlock";
import ConfirmDialog from './ConfirmDialog';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip'
import { debounce } from '../../utils';
import styles from './styles.scss';

export default class Pagination extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: props.index,
      type: props.type,
      config: props.config,
      data: props.data,
      currentPage: 1,
      dataPerPage: 20,
      enableActionBlock: props.enableActionBlock,
      confirmDialogIndex: null,
      confirmDialogActionName: null,
      confirmDialogData: null,
      width: 0
    };

    this.handleWindowResize = debounce(this.handleWindowResize.bind(this), 100); //delay trigger resize event
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ width: this.refs.pagination_wrapper.clientWidth })
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize);
  }

  handleWindowResize = () => {
    this.setState({ width: this.refs.pagination_wrapper.clientWidth })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="pagination_wrapper" className={styles.pagination_wrapper}>
        <ReactTooltip />
        {this.renderViewType()}
        {this.renderConfirmDialog()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Pagination.defaultProps = {
  enableActionBlock: true,
  dataPerPage: 20
};
```

And below is my test code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Pagination from '../index';
let img = 'https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg';
let imageStream = 'http://192.168.100.125:8080/';
let imgQuoteError = `http://192.168.100.71/target-data/fr/target-person-images/1111112222233333@Rizkifika-Asanuli'nam/qTD8vYa.jpeg`;

describe('Testing Pagination', () => {

  let action = (actionName, indexData) => {
    console.log('action APP', actionName, indexData);
  }

  let dataListProps = {
    index: 'id',
    type: 'grid',
    config: [
      { text: 'Image', type: 'image', textPath: 'image', textColor: 'red', valuePath: 'image' },
      { text: 'Fullname', type: 'string', textPath: 'fullname', valuePath: 'fullname' },
      { text: 'Role', type: 'string', textPath: 'role', valuePath: 'role' },
      { text: 'Datetime', type: 'date', textPath: 'datetime', valuePath: 'datetime' },
      { text: 'Json', type: 'json', textPath: 'json', valuePath: 'json' },
    ],
    data: [
      { id: 305, created_at: '2018-02-23T09:43:08.928Z', rule_detail: { id: 1 }, cam_detail: { id: 2, name: 'kamera huawei' }, vas_detail: { id: 3, name: 'VAS 3' }, image: img },
      { id: 306, created_at: '2018-02-23T09:43:08.928Z', rule_detail: { id: 2, name: '' }, cam_detail: { id: 3, name: 'kamera avigilon' }, vas_detail: { id: 4, name: 'VAS 4' }, image: imageStream },
      { id: 306, created_at: '2018-02-23T09:43:08.928Z', rule_detail: { id: 2, name: null }, cam_detail: { id: 3, name: 'kamera avigilon' }, vas_detail: { id: 4, name: 'VAS 4' }, image: imgQuoteError },
      { id: 306, created_at: '2018-02-23T09:43:08.928Z', rule_detail: { id: 2, name: 'Crowd Behaviour' }, cam_detail: { id: 3, name: 'kamera avigilon' }, vas_detail: { id: 4, name: 'VAS 4' }, image: imageStream },
    ],
    onAction: action,
    enableActionBlock: false
  }

  it('snapshot', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Pagination {...dataListProps}/>)
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  })
})
```

I need help for solving this

Comment: There is possible issue: ["If you want to test `refs` you have to mount."](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/316#issuecomment-208521009)

Comment: @Xarvalus can elaborate how to mount? i would be grateful

Comment: i understand now, use 'mount' from 'enyzme'. Its worked now, thanks men

Comment: @BIllySutomo any explanation, how did you resolved this problem? Can you post example of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `window` object inside your component, and so retrieve the `window.innerWidth` field which is, I guess, what you're looking for.

Comment: how do i access this innerWidth? i check inside the this.refs. There is no innerWidth

Comment: It is not inside this.refs, it's just the window object

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by [Xarvalus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2984693/xarvalus). If wanna access refs, the component have to be mounted first by using `mount` from `import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';`.

But it will have bug  (RangeError: Invalid string length). So to overcome this, we have to convert enzyme to json by using `import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';`

full working code

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme'; 
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'; 
import Pagination from '../index';

describe('Testing Pagination', () => {
  it('snapshot', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Pagination {...dataListProps}/>)
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();  
  }) 
})
```

[reference issue](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1050)